# Nemo: How can I fix 'A Problem has been detected with your thumbnail cache'?

Tags: linux-mint, nemo, thumbnails

I'm repeatedly seeing this message in nemo, despite clicking *Fix now* each time. I'd like to know if there's something I can do to fix the thumbnail cache once and for all.

A bug is [filed](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/issues/923) for when the thumbnail directories are symlinked to /tmp, but this isn't the case for me. However, I do have various symlinks in, out and within my ~/Pictures directory structure.

I've found references to `nemo --fix-cache`, but no docs (`man nemo` doesn't mention this option). It's occurred to me to try something like `sudo find -type d -exec nemo --fix-cache {} ;`, but I'm wary of this being an undocumented feature, and I don't want to stuff things up even more.

Does anybody have any experiences to share?

I'm running Nemo 2.6.7 under Mint 17.2.

Answer (score 3):

Some information that might makes it easier to track the issue.

## *--fix-cache*

The `--fix-cache` option was included in version 2.6.2. It is not in *man* but found by:

```
nemo --help
...
--fix-cache    Repair the user thumbnail cache - this can be useful if
               you're having trouble with file thumbnails.
               Must be run as root
```

From changelog:

> ```
> [ Michael Webster ]
> * Adapt Nemo to deal with problem situations with the user thumbnail cache: 
>   - Added --fix-cache command line option (must be run as root) 
>   - Added quick check at startup to detect major problems and disable
>     thumbnailing until fixed. 
>   - Individual thumbnailed files are checked on the fly for permission issues. 
>   - When a problem is detected, an infobar appears, offering to fix the problem,
>     or ignore it.
> * thumbnails: Remove an orphan comment from previous commits, 
>               fix wording of the --fix-cache command-line option.
> ```

## *ThumbnailFactory*

*Nemo* uses the [GnomeDesktopThumbnailFactory](https://developer.gnome.org/gnome-desktop3/stable/GnomeDesktopThumbnailFactory.html).

As such it creates a thumbnail in a cache directory. Typically `~/.thumbnails/[SIZE]` or `~/.cache/thumbnails/[SIZE]`. Where depends on system environment; more specifically *xdg* settings like `XDG_CACHE_HOME`. N.B! This is a *shared* cache that can be used by multiple applications.

The file name of a thumbnail is generated by hashing the original file's URI. The library can then check if the file is already cached by looking at the hash sum of the it's location.

If an error occurs a file is created in `.../thumbnails/fail/gnome-thumbnail-factory/[HASH].png`

## *Identify source for cached thumbnail*

*ThumbnailFactory* add *PNG tEXt* properties to the thumbnails. Among these are the *URI*. You can use various tools to extract this information, for example with Imagemagick:

```
identify -format "%[Thumb::URI]\n" ~/.cache/thumbnails/normal/774b4a5ba74455xxx.png
file:///home/foo/some_image.jpg
```

or the more verbose:

```
identify -format "%[*]" ~/.cache/thumbnails/normal/774b4a5ba74455xxx.png
```

or simply:

```
identify -verbose ~/.cache/thumbnails/normal/774b4a5ba74455xxx.png
```

This information is also stored in the *failed* thumbnails.

## *Custom thumbnail generator*

One can add custom thumbnail generators by adding configuration files in `share/thumbnailers`. Typically: `/usr/share/thumbnailers/` or `~/.local/share/thumbnailers`

Example taken from [arch Linux PCManFM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PCManFM#Thumbnail_support) for creating PDF thumbnails with Imagemagick:

```
[Thumbnailer Entry]
TryExec=convert
Exec=convert %i[0] -thumbnail %s %o
MimeType=application/pdf;application/x-pdf;image/pdf;
```

You could try this as a last resort. (Believe) *nemo* uses GTK library for thumbnail generation of images.

## *You might*

- Try to run the `--fix-cache` as *root*.
- Try to remove, (or move), the *thumbnails* cache directories – start fresh. *N.B: The cache directory is shared between applications using GnomeDesktopThumbnailFactory.*
- Run *nemo* from command line to see if any specific errors are reported.
- ...

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing this as of 2017 with Linux Mint 18.1 (Serena), so I think it merits an updated answer. This problem got registered both as [Github issue #1429](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/issues/1429) and Launchpad bug [#1592293](https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1592293).

The fix came with [this commit](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/commit/b58bea5384436fda9cb6b31f7010f72d3c74e76a), which got tagged to version 3.4.2 of Nemo, so that should be the released version that fixed the issue.

The solution to this problem is then to just get an updated version of Nemo. Updating to the latest release of Linux Mint (18.2) should be enough; however its Release Notes don't specify which is the exact version of Nemo included.